# When when sending an email of zip file size 19mb its not sending the email?

Tags: c#, winforms, gmail

This is in my new class top:

```
MailMessage photosmessage;
```

This is the method i have in my new class:

```
public void SendPhotos(string fileNameToSend)
        {
            try
            {
                MailAddress from = new MailAddress("chocolade@gmail.com", "User " + (char)0xD8 + " Name",
                System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
                MailAddress to = new MailAddress("MyEimalOfMyInternet");
                photosmessage = new MailMessage(from, to);
                photosmessage.Body = "Please check the log file attachment i have some bugs.";
                string someArrows = new string(new char[] { '\u2190', '\u2191', '\u2192', '\u2193' });
                photosmessage.Body += Environment.NewLine + someArrows;
                photosmessage.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                photosmessage.Subject = "Log File For Checking Bugs" + someArrows;
                photosmessage.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                Attachment myAttachment = new Attachment(fileNameToSend, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
                photosmessage.Attachments.Add(myAttachment);
                SmtpClient docsend = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
                docsend.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(docsend_SendCompleted);
                docsend.EnableSsl = true;
                docsend.Timeout = 10000;
                docsend.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                docsend.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                docsend.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("gmailusername", "gmailpassword");
                string userState = "test message1";
                docsend.SendAsync(photosmessage, userState);
                SendLogFile.Enabled = false;
            }

            catch (Exception errors)
            {
                Logger.Write("Error sending message :" + errors);
            }
        }
```

Im using this method in Form1 like this:

```
se.SendPhotos(outputtext+"\\"+"textfiles.zip");
se.SendPhotos(outputphotos + "\\" + "photofiles.zip");
```

Firsrt time its sending zipped file of some text files inside the zip file is about 5kb
Sending the zip file no problems.

Then its sending a zip file of 19mb that inside there are some images/photos each photos about 7.55mb
This time the zip file never get to my email.

The first zip file of the text files i get it but the second one i never get it.
Im using my gmail email account to send this files to my regular isp email account.

I know in gmail you cant send more then 25mb but the zip file of the photos is 19mb

What else could be the reason i never get the second zip file ?

Edit:

I think i know what is the problem.
When getting and creating the zip of text file i did a filter "*.txt" but when doing it with the photos zip file i did "*.*" all the files:

```
string[] photosfiles = Directory.GetFiles(s, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

The result is i had a file with .ini in the zip file.

How can i filter for all images types ?

```
string[] photosfiles = Directory.GetFiles(s, "*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

This will work for jpg files only but if i want also to get png or bmp ?

Comment: Maybe the ISP is blocking it?

Comment: Maybe didnt think about it. Why my isp will block zip files ? Or 19mb is too much big ? i will check with them strange.

Comment: As @cadrell0 said, you may be using the wrong system for this: always expect that any server involved can deny an attachment due to its size or file type. Use FTP.

Comment: Which account is not getting the file.  Google or your ISP account?  Update your question to clarify this.

Comment: My ISP is not getting the second zip file the bigger one the 19mb.

Comment: How can i send email to fpt ? Lets say i have an ftp with 40gb space how can i send email to ftp ?

Comment: Edited my question with something that might doing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the added question (in your `Edit`), you can use the following code to get all the files you want:

```
 string[] extensions = {"*.bmp","*.jpg","*.png", "*.gif" };//add extensions you want to filter first
 var filenames = extensions.SelectMany(x => Directory.GetFiles(s, x));
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try sending a simple text file to vet your solution even works. If that comes through, then your ISP may be filtering. Some ISP's have 5mb limits. Also make sure you only have pictures in those zips. If you have any exes etcs those can be blocked. Check your spam folder.

Really though, just make sure a text attachment goes through.

Answer (score 0):

Do the attachments only contain photos and text files, Google will open up zip files and check to see if you're not attaching anything that could be potentially dangerous (*.exe, .bat, etc.*)

Or, you could be sending a zip file within of your zip files.  (see [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6590) for a full list of what can't be sent over Gmail)

I would imagine in any case where you are violating a sending condition, the SMTP request would be implicitly rejected.

Is the photo zip file just photos? I tried looking online to see if Gmail does implement further restrictions on SMTP requests but couldn't find anything...